# Driver for Wireless 7260

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, intel, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with Intel Wireless 7260, but the kernel does not recognize wifi. The laptop does not have ethernet, and wifi is my only way to connect to the internet.

As I searched, many people have this problem.

One issue that I see is that the intel driver for kernel 4.3+ should be `iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode`, but Ubuntu uses `iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode`.

In `/lib/firmware`, `iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode` is available. I downloaded `iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode` and `iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode` from Intel website, but still no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one day of struggling, I found it has nothing to do with driver.

If anyone has this problem, the solution is

```
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I don't know what is this problem, but I believe it should be permanently fixed.