# No WiFi adapter found - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)

Tags: wireless, 18.04

I installed my Ubuntu 18.04 two days ago and it was working fine until I installed `VMware` in it as I had to install MAC.

It was working fine after the installation of `vmware` but the problem appears when I restart my laptop. [Here is a link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/X3YJMMYyW3/) to the `pastebin` output.

I've tried many solutions like `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` but was not useful for me.

Comment: When I search AskUbuntu for [wireless 7260](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=wireless+7260) I get 380 results, at least 50 of which seem to describe your problem. Please edit your question to make clear how your issue is different from these other questions.

Comment: Thanks for you time @zwets. Actually the thing is I'm pretty much new to Ubuntu and It's hard for me to tell any difference from those issues but as I said I tried many solution from AskUbuntu but no one work in my case.
I'm listing down the solutions which I tried.
[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/760913/858316), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/573083), [3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392454&p=13769188#post13769188)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue it was not related to `VMWare` installation.

Actually I setup a `DSL` connection on my laptop through `pppoeconf` 1 week before this problem happened and didn't restart my laptop since then but on the day of `VM` installation when I restart my laptop this problem appears so I thought that it's related to `VM` installation.

I just edited the `interfaces` file in `/etc/network` and commented out the last two lines which resolved my issue.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set wlp3s0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

#auto wlp3s0
#iface wlp3s0 inet manual
```