# No Wi-Fi adapter found (22.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, dell

```
 *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: bb
       serial: 10:4a:7d:2f:df:a5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-58-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff

network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl

farhad@fbm:~/Desktop$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Driver for Wireless 7260](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760501/driver-for-wireless-7260)

Comment: Please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`.

Comment: @karel Why do you think OP has an Acer?

Comment: sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[   13.725165] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   16.478681] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[   16.485135] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[   16.485158] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   16.499142] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 10:4a:7d:2f:df:a5
[   16.517751] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   16.787467] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0

Comment: Please add information to the question using [edit]. Also please add output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: What is the laptop model?

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsmod | grep dell`

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless device is hard-blocked. Try to find a hardware switch. It is either a physical button, or some Fn+Fx key combination. The wireless device can be also disabled in BIOS.

In case there is no hardware switch, you can blacklist `dell_wmi` kernel module. But it is the last resort.

Run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-dellwmi.conf <<< "blacklist dell_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142632/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-no-wi-fi-adapter-found-22-04); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.